# UIAlertView with two buttons in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uialertview

I'm trying show an alert view when a button was pressed, so I wrote code as follows:

```
- (IBAction)signUpComplete: (id)sender {
  UIAlertView* alert_view = [[UIAlertView alloc]
      initWithTitle: @"test" message: @"test" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"OK"];
  [alert_view show];
  [alert_view release];
}
```

But this code crashes with the following exception in the initWithTitle method:

> 2010-08-11 03:03:18.697 Polaris[1155:207] *** -[UIButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176af0
>   2010-08-11 03:03:18.700 Polaris[1155:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception

0x176af0 is the same as the value of the argument 'sender', which is the button whose action handler is signUpComplete:. I think the problem is the otherButtonTitles: parameter, because it works fine with the argument nil. So it has a problem with creating the OK button.
Is there anything wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Comment: can you show us how you are creating the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

otherButtonTitles list must be nil-terminated:

```
UIAlertView* alert_view = [[UIAlertView alloc]
      initWithTitle: @"test" message: @"test" delegate: nil 
      cancelButtonTitle: @"cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"OK", nil];
```

Comment: @Vladimir How can one call a method when the OK button is clicked?

Comment: @Prashant, you can use alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: delegate method, but not that UIAlertView is deprecated as of iOS 9 and you should use UIAlertController instead

Comment: @Vladimir, thank you. Figured this one out. I have to use the old methods as it is the current requirement. Appreciate your help.